# Using storage spaces like raid 0 + mirroring?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, raid, mirroring, storage-spaces

I have a few drives I'd like to use but I'd get more space out of them if (this assumes its possible) I could set the two smaller drives up like raid zero, then have the "raid 0 drive" mirror a x3 larger drive rather than putting them all in a pool which seems to yield less space. Thing is, I am not sure that is possible? Thoughts (on how to do it).

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it's possible, but you need a controller of some sort to do the actual RAID itself. If you just want a "large volume", you can do that without the need for RAID, Windows and Linux allow you to "combine" multiple disks as one large "span". Are you trying to do this from a laptop/PC/NAS?

Comment: And remember: RAID is not backup :)

Comment: Especially Raid 0, which is not raid at all because there is no redundancy.

Comment: Are you trying to span all the drives so that you just have one big one?